# Unhide all cells in Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

Is there a way to unhide all hidden cells in a Jupyter notebook on Google Colab?

It appears that google colab hides cells automatically.  Is there a way to unhide all cells?  It's a pain to click each hidden cell especially when they are nested.  And I sometimes inadvertently skip over hidden cells when reviewing a notebook.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to expand all Colab hidden cells. Both from the menu:

1. **Edit --> Select all cells**
2. **View --> Expand Sections**

Answer (score 2):

First, select all cells.

[image]

Then, right click and select 'Show code' from the context menu..

[image]

Also available in the command palette is 'expand all sections'.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The first method did not work for me.  It added `#@title` to each code cell and only half of the code cells were visible and some sections were not expanded.  In the second method, typing "exp" shows me only the second option (for Toggle expand/collapse current section) and not the first.

Answer (score 1):

Want to add additional point to 2nd Answer from @j2abro.

There is also **Collapse Sections** option under **View**.

1. **Edit --> Select all cells**
2. **View --> Collapse Sections**

This is very similar to the problem we generally encounter of hidden cells while we are working.

Therefore We can Select **View --> Expand Sections** as mentioned above in 2nd Answer.

Answer (score 0):

right now you just need to click `left arrow` to hide all cells... `right arrow` to unhide all cells.

but to work you need to have a cell selected (any cell).